# Add button don't add new row on the tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I add my button also the tableView who contain the array and I want that when I click on the button add it adds the content of the textField in the array that will be displayed on the tableViewController

```
-(void) add:(UIButton *)sender{
    [tableViewController._myArray addObject:headerView._searchTextField.text ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you update the Data source of a tableview you need to reload the tableview to see the updated changes you're missing reloadData mehtod for your tableview controller :-

```
-(void) add:(UIButton *)sender{
    [tableViewController._myArray addObject:headerView._searchTextField.text ];
    [tableview reloadData]; // considering tableview is you variable holding reference of UITableView
}
```